# Getting the rank based on the column

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query where I want to add a `rank` column.

```
SELECT AM.* , count(ALM.id) as likes FROM admin_models as AM
            left join admin_liked_models as ALM on AM.id = ALM.admin_model_id
            group by AM.id
```

`admin_models` and `admin_liked_models` has a one to many relationship.

The highest `likes` should be rank 1.

Can anyone point me out how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support `Row_Number()` or other analytic functions.  Here is one way to produce the same results though:

```
SELECT *,
    @rn:=@rn+1 rn
FROM (
    SELECT AM.* , count(ALM.id) as likes 
    FROM admin_models as AM
            LEFT JOIN admin_liked_models as ALM ON AM.id = ALM.admin_model_id
    GROUP BY AM.id
) t, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
ORDER BY likes DESC
```

You probably don't need the subquery, but I'm just showing the separation.

Comment: this only works when using with `ORDER BY` is it not possible to make the `rank` column based on the number of `likes` column?

Comment: @galao -- this does create the rank column by ordering the number of likes.  I don't think you can create a ranking column without ordering by some column, if not, what is it ranking.  Perhaps I'm not understanding your question, but you are limited to your RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

> this only works when using with ORDER BY is it not possible to make the rank column based on the number of likes column?

It looks you are not looking for `rank`. If you do not want to use `ORDER` and want to use the rank as some grade, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT AM.* , count(ALM.id) as likes,

((SELECT max(maxval) from
   (SELECT count(ALM.id) as maxval  FROM admin_models as AM
        left join admin_liked_models as ALM on AM.id = ALM.admin_model_id
        group by AM.id) as subq) - count(ALM.id) + 1) as rank

FROM admin_models as AM
        left join admin_liked_models as ALM on AM.id = ALM.admin_model_id
        group by AM.id
```

Please note that in this case the grade will not be sequential, and several models will have the same grade.